# smarty if file exists

Tags: php, smarty

как в smarty произвести проверку `file_exists` ?
мой вариант не находит картинки:

```
{foreach from=$item.item_img key=id item=i}
    {if file_exists("{$host}/item_images/$i")}
    <div class="item-small-image{if $id==0} selected{/if}" style="background-image: url({$host}/item_images/{$i});" data-name="{$i}">
    </div>
    {else}
    <div class="item-small-no-image">
        <img src="{$host}/images/no_image.jpg"/>
    </div>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: такие вещи обычно не делаются в шаблоне. в целом это возможно, конечно. судя по коду (bg-image url), у вас `$host` содержит путь относительно корня сайта, а для `file_exists` потребуется абсолютный путь в файловой системе.

Comment: @teran соответственно автору просто нужно в `file_exists` изменить $host, где путь относительно сайта на какой-нибудь $path, где путь относительно директории изображений в файловой системе, чтобы был типа: `/var/www/site.ru/images/`

Comment: @lampa автору нужно перенести код поиска изображения в контроллер/пхп-логику, а не загромождать шаблон несвойственными задачами

Comment: @teran это понятно, но автор просит другое.